# JS Tabs не переключаются вкладки

Tags: php, javascript, html

Знатоки, подскажите, пожалуйста, как переключиться на другую вкладку?

```js
var formOne = $('form#s-1');
var formTwo = $('form#s-2');
var formThree = $('form#s-3');
var buttonRole = $('[role="presentation"]');

formOne.submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    url: "/forgot",
    type: "POST",
    data: new FormData(this),
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData:false,
    success: function(data){
      if(data.success == true){ 
        $('#step-1').removeClass('active');
        $('#step-2').addClass('active');
        buttonRole.eq(0).removeClass('active');
        buttonRole.eq(1).addClass('active');
      }else{
       $("#res").html(data);
       setTimeout(function(){
        $('#res').show().delay(1000).fadeOut();
      },  500); 
     }
     
   }
   
 });
});
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation" class="active">
    <a href="#step-1" aria-controls="step-1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Step-1</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Step-2</a></li>
  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Step-3</a></li>
</ul>


<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="step-1">
  <form method="POST" id="s-1">
    <div class="youplay-input">
      <input type="text" id="loginOrEmail" name="loginOrEmail" placeholder="<?php echo $Lang['mes137']; ?>" required/>
    </div>
    <center>
      <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </center>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Не понятно что за событие `javascript`- а `submit` ? Если тут нет ни какой формы? И кнопки с типом `submit`. Наверное вы хотели `formOne.click(function (e)`

Comment: @StackOverflow обновила код

Comment: @StackOverflow форм клик постоянно отправляет данные, независимо от того, куда кликнуть (